# Getting an "unexpected '}' error when writing a function and can't tell why

Tags: r, function, syntax

I'm writing a function, which I've never done before. I want to take a table generated by prop.table() and add the first two cells together. I think my script makes sense, but I keep getting an "unexpected '}' in '}'" error.

```
likert <- c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f')

percSat <- function(likert) {
  propTable <- prop.table(table(women$qualitySchools))
  percSatisfied <- sum(propTable[1:2])
  return(percSatisfied)
}

#OR

percSat <- function(likert) {
  percSatisfied <- sum(prop.table(table(likert))[1:2])
  return(percSatisfied)
}
```

I've tried running it in a script and in the console in RStudio. For some reason I don't get an error in regular R. I can definitely believe that I've done something wrong, but I can't see any mistakes with the bracketing so I'm very confused.

Comment: I can not reproduce the error.

Comment: ^^^ Ditto here. `percSat(likert)` works just fine. Please check your code again.

Comment: The code as presented here makes sense and is syntactically valid (although the variable `women` is not defined here). You will have to take a step back and look at the context of which you are calling this code. As you wrote, you don't get an error in regular R, so when *do* you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

There must have been some floating punctuation in another part of the script; once I started a new one, percSat(likert) worked perfectly. Sorry all!